# Clear all checkboxes in Word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word

One of the managers at my workplace has decided to roll out a document with over a thousand checkboxes in it.

There is a button to clear all the checkboxes, but she's written out every line like:

```
Checkbox1.Value = False
Checkbox2.Value = False
...
Checkbox999.Value = False
Checkbox1000.Value = False
```

Now I, as the IT helpdesk guy, have to resolve her issue of everyone in her department having 60+ seconds delay when opening this document.

We are both noobs at this, and I imagine she just went online for her code.

Can anyone share a quick way to clear all checkboxes in one go?

Would that speed it up?

Thanks in advance.

PS I found this code that works in Excel, though I don't know how to adapt it to Word...

```
Sub ClearCheckBoxes()
    Dim chkBox As Excel.CheckBox
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each chkBox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
            chkBox.Value = xlOff
    Next chkBox
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What code can be used depends very much on what kind of checkbox these are. Word has at least three different kinds - and the code for each kind differs totally. If you don't know what kind: **How were these checkboxes inserted into the document?** What commands were used?

Comment: Thanks Cindy, yes, the problem ended up being the checkbox type.

It was ActiveX instead of Content Control.

I managed to reduce file size from 1.5MB to 240KB, and decrease load delay from 30-90 seconds, down to less than 3 seconds!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Excel VBA code you posted can be translated into Word VBA fairly easily (if you know what to google)

By using the Macro Recorder, I figured out that checkboxes are called content controls in Word. [(More is explained in the MSDN Docs here.)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/contentcontrol-object-word) Then you just need the content control type "wdContentControlCheckBox" to get you all the checkboxes.

**This code should do what you need:**

```
Sub ClearCheckBoxes()
    Dim ctrl As Word.ContentControl
    For Each ctrl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
            If ctrl.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
                ctrl.Checked = False
            End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Comment: No worries, I've just been having a fun time translating my Excel VBA skills to Visio VBA (which was a struggle!) and I've found that MSDN documentation and good googling habits always come in handy!